# REGEX: get Create table queries in sql dump

Tags: regex

I have an sql dump of different tables each with different amount of fields, I want to insert a query after each one, so I'm trying to find a regex statment that would retreive:

```
CREATE TABLE  cms_audit (
aud_id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  user_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  client_id int NOT NULL,
  aud_event varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  aud_type varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  aud_string varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  aud_date datetime DEFAULT NULL
) 
-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

My regex is `CREATE TABLE .*--` (in notepad++ I've checked the box that say's . matches newline) in my head this means get all that starts with "create table" and whatever is after it until you reach "--".
However this statement is retrieving the entire file instead of getting each "create table" query separately, what am I missing?.

I have also tried `CREATE TABLE (.*|\n)*--`.. didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regex with any character except `--`. To achieve this you can do:

`CREATE TABLE (?:(?!--).)*`

**EDIT**

The `?!` is to make a Negative Lookahead of the string `--`. Nothing with this string will match this expression.

You can see and test it with this link (it's very well explained and a good tool):

https://regex101.com/r/mR9fD4/1

Comment: That works! Thanks.
Why do I have to use the `?!` though? can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Thanks. Why wouldn't this work though? `CREATE TABLE (?:(?!--).*)`

Comment: Because `*` repeats only the last character (in this case anything as you put a `.`) although you'd put `(?!--)`. So this, match all the string. You should put the  `*` after all the group to say that must match anything (`.`) expect `--` any times (`*`). I hope it is clearer ;)