# Regex for selecting a whole mysql table structure in php

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I have this table structure in an SQL file.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_table_name` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_another_table_name` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Somehow I read the `.sql` file and want to detect the individual `table` structure using `regex`.

I've tried this `Regex` but it's not working as expected.

```
^create\stable.+`.+`\s?\(.*(\n.*)+;$
```

**Note:** My expected output is to extract two tables and put them into an array.

```
$output = array(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_table_name` (
        `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;",

    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_table_name` (
        `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;"
);
```

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30771560/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a regex like below:

```
preg_match_all('/create table\s+(if not exists\s+)?(`.+`)/i',$str,$matches);
```

- Match/make the `create table` string as is.
- Make `if not exists` optional as it may or may not exist.
- For table names, match all characters that are enclosed within backticks.
- Make the match case insensitive using the `i` modifier.
- Now in the above regex, group 2 will have all the tables names with back ticks.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_table_name` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_another_table_name` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;";


preg_match_all('/create table\s+(if not exists\s+)?(`.+`)/i',$str,$matches);

print_r($matches[2]);
```

**Update:**

To match all the create table statements, your regex can look like:

```
preg_match_all('/create table\s+[^;]+;/i',$str,$matches);
```

- Match all statements that start with `create table`.
- Match all non-semicolon characters in `[^;]+` followed by a semicolon(marking the end of the statement).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_table_name` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref_another_table_name` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;";




preg_match_all('/create table\s+[^;]+;/i',$str,$matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you @vivek_23, But I am afraid that you are just considering the first line of the table structure. I need the full table structure individually.

Comment: This is correct. Please make your update as the actual answer.

Comment: The `m` flag is useless unless `^` or `$` metachatacters exist in your pattern.  Your explanation is giving false information to the OP and researchers.  The capture group is also of no benefit.  Writing `CREATE TABLE` means that you can safely remove the `i` flag.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for correcting. I have removed the `m` modifier and it's explanation as it was redundant(and likely irrelevant as well). I would the keep the `i` flag as I find it safe just in case some create table statements are in lower case.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed I am keeping both versions just in case someone needs the first version.